# React : How to make the SAME component re-render?

Tags: reactjs

I've found myself at a bit of dead end here. I'll try to explain it as best as I can.

I'm using base username routing on my app, meaning that website.com/username will route to username's profile page.  Everything works fine apart from one issue that I'll get to below.

This is how I'm doing it (very short version) :

This route looks for a potential username and renders the Distribution component.

```
<Route exact path="/([0-9a-z_]+)" component={Distribution} />
```

Distribution component then extracts the potential username from the pathname...

```
username = {
  username: this.props.location.pathname.substring(1)
};
```

...And then fires that off to my API which checks to see if that username actually exists and belongs to a valid user. If it does it returns a user object, if not it returns an error.

```
if (username) {
  axios
    .post(API_URI + '/users/get/profile', JSON.stringify(username))
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        ready: true,
        data: res.data,
        error: ''
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.setState({
        ready: true,
        data: '',
        error: err.response
      });
    });
}
```

All of the above is happening inside `componentWillMount`.

I then pass the relevant state info as props to the relevant child component in the `render` :

```
render() {
  if (this.state.ready) {
    if (this.state.data) {
      return <UserProfile profile={this.state.data} />;
    }
    if (this.state.error) {
      return <Redirect to="notfound" />;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

As I mentioned, this all works perfectly when moving between all of the other routes / components, but it fails when the Distribution component is called while already IN the Distribution component. For example, if you are already looking at a valid profile (which is at Distribution > UserProfile), and then try to view another profile, (or any other malformed username route that would throw an error), the API call isn't getting fired again so the state isn't being updated in the Distribution component.

I originally had it all set up with a Redux store but had the exact same problem. I wrongly thought that `componentDidMount` would be fired every single time the component is called for the first time, and I assumed that throwing a new url at it would cause that but it doesn't.

I've tried a bunch of different ways to make this work (`componentWillReceiveProps` etc) but I just can't figure it out. Everything I try throws depth errors.

Am I missing a magical piece of the puzzle here or just not seeing something really obvious?

Am I going about this entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You on the right path when you tried to use `componentWillReceiveProps`. I would do something like the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.refresh()
}

componentWillReceiveProps(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.location.pathname !== this.props.location.pathname) {
        this.refresh(prevProps)
    }
}

refresh = (props) => {
    props = props || this.props
    // get username from props
    // ...
    if (username) {
        // fetch result from remote
    }
}
```

Comment: p.s. that's pattern I use quite often when I need to update a component due to props passed from a parent component change. Let us know if that works for you.

Comment: You absolute legend! That worked beautifully. My mistake when trying it with `componentWillReceiveProps` before was not using `prevProps`. I had totally forgotten they existed. Thank you so much bro!

Comment: No problem at at. glad it helps.